# Wifi/Ethernet at the same time but with a twist!

Tags: 14.04, networking

As I'm sure some of you have seen on here, there are questions pertaining to using Wifi/Ethernet at the same time.

My problem is similar, just now the Ethernet doesn't have any internet.

I'm experimenting with an old router and I don't want to choose one connection over the other, since I'm flashing custom firmware to it and switching between the two connections is becoming a chore. I'm still not quite sure how to go about doing this.

I am running 14.04 LTS atm.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just force routing through one interface or the other for these IP addresses you need to access via that interface?